# json array index duplication

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am creating a json array and obtain data from an arraylist. 
My problem is that when I save the data in my json it only saves the last data of the arraylist to each index.

This is my code:

```
 JSONArray ItemsRequiredobArr=new JSONArray();

            JSONObject ItemsRequiredob=new JSONObject();

            for(int ii=0;ii<StocklistAdapter.listItemN.size();ii++){


                ItemsRequiredob.put("ItemID",StocklistAdapter.itemIdN.get(ii));
                ItemsRequiredob.put("StockCode",StocklistAdapter.listItemN.get(ii));
                Toast.makeText(this, "StockCode"+StocklistAdapter.listItemN.get(ii), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ItemsRequiredob.put("Description",StocklistAdapter.listAddressN.get(ii));
                ItemsRequiredob.put("Quantity",StocklistAdapter.QuaN.get(ii));

                ItemsRequiredobArr.put(ItemsRequiredob);


                        /*Toast.makeText(mContext, "i"+i+" "+listAddressN.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    Log.e("d", ItemsRequiredob.get("ItemID").toString());


            }
            ob.put("ItemsRequired",ItemsRequiredobArr);
```

this is my array from above

```
[{"ItemsRequired":[{"ItemID":"3224","StockCode":"10030","Description":"Complete - 3 section mattress\r\n\r\nPolyeurethane velcro grips","Quantity":"0"},{"ItemID":"3224","StockCode":"10030","Description":"Complete - 3 section mattress\r\n\r\nPolyeurethane velcro grips","Quantity":"0"}]
```

As you can see both index have the same data but arraylist contains different data on index 0 and 1. 
Please help me out since I am a beginner.

Comment: Make ItemsRequiredob object inside the loop. You are overriding the same object all the times

Comment: you add same object into your list for multiple times. You have to create new JSONObject each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ItemsRequiredob object created one time and you are setting the value every time so it's talking the last item for every object, so Put `ItemsRequiredob` inside for loop like this, it will work fine

```
            for(int ii=0;ii<StocklistAdapter.listItemN.size();ii++){
JSONObject ItemsRequiredob=new JSONObject();

                ItemsRequiredob.put("ItemID",StocklistAdapter.itemIdN.get(ii));
                ItemsRequiredob.put("StockCode",StocklistAdapter.listItemN.get(ii));
                Toast.makeText(this, "StockCode"+StocklistAdapter.listItemN.get(ii), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ItemsRequiredob.put("Description",StocklistAdapter.listAddressN.get(ii));
                ItemsRequiredob.put("Quantity",StocklistAdapter.QuaN.get(ii));

                ItemsRequiredobArr.put(ItemsRequiredob);


                        /*Toast.makeText(mContext, "i"+i+" "+listAddressN.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    Log.e("d", ItemsRequiredob.get("ItemID").toString());


            }
```